# Assembler (.asm) function not listed in map file after building

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to build a TI CCS project (cl2000 v4.1.3) which contains a assembler file also. And after build, when I checked the map file I am able to see only A201CodeStart listed and I cannot see A202WD_Disable and A203ClearRAM. What might be the reason for it? Is the .global directive reason behind it?
And if yes what is the address for the functions which are not available in map file

Example asm source :

```
   .global _A300Main
   .global A201CodeStart

   .sect "codestrt"

A201CodeStart:**(Available in map file)**

   LB    A202WD_Disable       ;Branch to watchdog disable code

   .text
A202WD_Disable:**(not available in map file)**

   SETC  OBJMODE              ;Set OBJMODE for 28x object code
   EALLOW
   MOVZ  DP, #7029h>>6     
   MOV   @7029h, #0068h       
   EDIS                       
   LB    A203ClearRAM


A203ClearRAM: **(not available in map file)**
   ....
```

Comment: You probably need to put a `.global` in front of each one.

Comment: OK. Yeah but if that is not given with a .global directive, at runtime how will the program know the starting address of these functions... Is it like these are allocated memory at runtime etc? Please let me know.... But with other functions in c file even without extern keyword all are being listed....

Comment: I'm guessing the numbers within those function names have assertions to the data alignment. For variable names though within the actual assembly (eg. `XAR3`) would need to get `.set XAR3` or something similar. I haven't worked with this particular flavor of assembly, but that's how `DMAC` instructions are, which I presume is similar to this; correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The `LB` is the only one that looks out of place in your list. It's generally a function call that would be used with a `*XAR7` instruction...

Comment: So you mean to say the functions that are not listed in map file will be available continuously in the memory after A201CodeStart function? I want to know the starting address for the functions for all functions that are not listed in map file... I have updated the code snippet with actual code in my orginal question for you ref.....

Comment: Please let me know if I am wrong

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to know the starting addresses for the functions not in the map file, but it's likely the code uses **[PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)** anyway, so there would be no absolute addresses for the functions. If you want to see those symbols you are referring to then put the compiled code into a disassembler and you should be able to see everything there.

Comment: I need to know if all symbols intended are available in map file. And, I guess as you said it can be PICode, I will check the disassembly.. Thanks very much... :)

Comment: Try using the assembler's `--output_all_syms` option.